# Passing for each values to php script

Tags: php

I am passing a table data value within a for each loop to the php script. The problem here is that when I try to `echo $exchange;`. I don't get any values of the specific product name. The product name being displayed in the form is item1.

```
<form action="exchangeItem" method="post">    
 <tbody>
                    <?php
                      $query = "SELECT * FROM product";
                      $data = $MySQLi_CON->query($query);
                      foreach ($data as $key ) {              
                    ?>
                    <tr>                            
                      <td class="id"><h3><input type="hidden" name="productName" ><?php echo $key['product_Name'];?></h3>
                      </td>
                    <input name = "id" type = "hidden" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
                    <td id="exchange_button">
                          <input value="Exchange" name="exchange_submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-md raised exchange_submit">
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php
                      }
                      ?>                     
    </tbody>
</form>
```

## exchangeItem.php

```
<?php
    $exchange = $_POST['productName'];
    echo $exchange;
    exit;
?>
```

Comment: try using action="exchangeItem.php" instead of action="exchangeItem" in form

Comment: exchangeItem works fine too cause I have set the php site to work without extension

Comment: did you tried to print some other value then the posted one in the exchangeItem.php ?

Answer (score 1):

This

```
<td class="id"><h3><input type="hidden" name="productName" ><?php echo $key['product_Name'];?></h3>
```

Should be:

```
<td class="id"><h3><input type="hidden" name="productName" value="<?php echo $key['product_Name'];?>" ></h3>
```

Comment: i don't want my values to be hidden

Comment: Then why still use this? `$exchange = $_POST['productName'];`

Comment: sorry, I can't find a better way to fetching the value of <?php echo $key['product_Name'];?>

Comment: What is your reason that you don't want it to be in an input box?

Comment: even If i did use it as an input box, it only shows the first item in the list when I select item2

Comment: and I want to display it as a table data instead of a input box, then pass the table data to php script

Answer (score 0):

Set value for you hidden element... No need to place the hidden element in the header tag. Use `productName[]` for posting array of values.

```
<td class="id">
    <h3><?php echo $key['product_Name'];?></h3>
    <input type="hidden" name="productName[]" value="<?php echo $key['product_Name'];?>">
</td>
```

foreach all posted values to print.

```
<?php
    $exchange = $_POST['productName'];
    foreach($exchange as $key) {
        echo $key;
    }
    exit;
?>
```

**Update for select**

Change yout html for select values..

```
<td class="id">
    <h3><input type="checkbox" name="productName[]" value="<?php echo $key['product_Name'];?>"><?php echo $key['product_Name'];?></h3>
</td>
```

Comment: I have tried this previously, it seems to only echo item1 though there are item2, item3

Comment: it's passing all the values from my database, not the selected one :(

Comment: I have added an update in my answer for select option

Comment: is there other way besides than selecting checkbox as select option. I only just want it display the data and an exchange button next to it. So when I select exchange, it retrieves the value of data displayed

Comment: When using select option, you can choose only one item at a time.. or you use multi select.

Answer (score 0):

first, edit your **td**

```
<td class="id"><h3><input type="hidden" name="productName[]" value="<?php echo $key['product_Name'];?>" ></h3>
```

your name => productName should be in array thats why you need bracket **[ ]**, because you use foreach. then your post will be in array too.

**exchangeItem.php**

```
<?php
    print_r($_POST['productName']);
    exit;
?>
```

Comment: it says array to string conversion

Comment: did u use print_r?? or echo?? if echo, then u need to loop $_POST['productName'] into string. because $_POST['productName'] is array type, see @noufalcep answer to looping it into string.

Answer (score 0):

I have added & changed your 2 input name `productName[]` , `id[]` and your form action `exchangeItem.php` if you get product name must be used input name with array like `[]` because you are used `foreach` loop.

```
<form action="exchangeItem.php" method="post">    
    <tbody>
    <?php
        $query = "SELECT * FROM product";
        $data = $MySQLi_CON->query($query);
        foreach ($data as $key ) {              
            ?>
            <tr>                            
                <td class="id">
                    <h3><input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $key['product_Name'];?>" name="productName[]" ><?php echo $key['product_Name'];?></h3>
                    <input name="id[]" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <?php
        }
    ?>                     
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
          <tr>                            
             <td id="exchange_button">
                <input value="Exchange" name="exchange_submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-md raised exchange_submit">
             </td>
         </tr>
    </tfoot>
</form>
```

exchangeItem.php

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['exchange_submit'])) {
       $exchange = $_POST['productName'];
       foreach($exchange as $product_name) {
           echo $product_name;
       }
    }
?>
```

Comment: I have tried this, but the value passed is still null

Comment: now, you can see my edited answer. i have added `value="<?php echo $key['product_Name'];?>"` in productName input. and let me know.

Comment: it's passing all the product names from my database, not the selected product name :(

Comment: you can used `<tfoot></tfoot>` html tag and `submit button` you keep out of your `foreach` loop. follow my last edited answer. let me know.

Comment: i need the button to be in for loop, so that it goes as the same row as my product

Comment: I thinks you keep your `<form>` and `</form>` under loop.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you facing here is with this code

```
    <td class="id">
        <h3><input type="hidden" name="productName" ><?php echo $key['product_Name'];?></h3>
    </td>
```

here in the input field you didn't have added the value, that's why when you trying to print the posted value in your action file it's showing none. So just add add value to the input field

```
    <td class="id">
        <h3><input type="hidden" name="productName" value="<?php echo $key['product_Name'];?>"></h3>
    </td>
```